# Removing activity background gradient in holo theme. Throwing SIGSEGV like crazy

Tags: android

So, my app has the android:hardwareAccelerated="true" flag in its manifest, and I also set it to use the Holo Dark theme for my main activity:

android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle"

My style file (for API Lvl > 11):

```
<style name="Theme.NoTitle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

There are no issues with the above style file, however I still get that dark blue/grey gradient activity background used in the Holo theme. So, based on the documentation, I change my style file by adding the windowBackground property:

```
<style name="Theme.NoTitle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

This works, in the sense that it replaces the Holo background gradient with a solid black color. But my app will randomnly start throwing SIGNAL 11 SIGSEGV crashes left and right. My app is rock solid and reliable until I make this simple change.

I've also tried setting the window background to transparent and I get the same issue.

Is there any way of changing the activity background in a holo themed application without it crashing like crazy?